# Fluentd to Logstash output plugin

Tags: logging, logstash, log-shipping, fluentd

I am trying to read from the scribe server using flunetd and output those logs to be stored in logstash for now. I know it's very stupid to log the scribe_central logs to another central logger, but we need this to be done in our current architecture.

Does anyone know if there is any plugin to do that? I searched Google but could not find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Scribe <-> Fluentd, there is [fluent-plugin-scribe](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-scribe):

For Fluentd <-> Logstash, a couple of options:

1. Use Redis in the middle, and use [fluent-plugin-redis](https://github.com/yuki24/fluent-plugin-redis) and input_redis on Logstash's side. So it would be Fluentd -> Redis -> Logstash. This is what Logstash recommends anyway with log shippers + Logstash.
2. Alternatively, you can use Fluentd's out_forward plugin with Logstash's TCP input. Logstash has Fluentd codec to handle the input coming from Fluentd.

Comment: Since this post is almost a year old, do you know if there's a new options to do it ?

Comment: What are you looking for specifically? The outlined solution still works.

Comment: The solution Kiyoto Tamura mentioned, about using Fluentd forwarding to Logstash, is not working. I have tried without success. Fluentd keeps saying "no nodes are available".

Comment: please notice that the out_forward  is not secured (ssl), and the out_secure_forward is only between fluentd sender and fluentd receiver.

Answer (score 4):

You can forward it directly to your logstash tcp input :)

I wrote a [flunetd output plugin](https://github.com/loomltd/fluent-plugin-loomsystems) for forwarding fluentd events to a generic receiver through a **secured** tcp connection (can be configured for non-secured as well).

To add the plugin to your fluentd agent, use the following command:

```
gem install fluent-plugin-loomsystems
```

Also see full [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46264096/3142017), good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with http output from fluentd and http input for logstash, below the configuration snippets:

fluentd:

```
<match **>
    @type http
    endpoint_url http://logstash-box:8080/
    http_method put
    serializer json
    raise_on_error false
</match>
```

Logstash:

```
input {
    http {
        port => 8080 
    }
}
```

Obs: You may have to install the plugin `gem install fluent-plugin-out-http`

Comment: 504 Gateway Time-out when trying to push to logstash.