# Fluentd SSL/TLS secured TCP output plugin to generic receiver (Logstash)?

Tags: ssl, tcp, rubygems, logstash, fluentd

I've been looking for a while for fluentd output plugin for tcp which is also ssl secured that doesn't force my receiver to be from a specific kind.
In my case, my receiver is logstash.

Here are a few of the plugins which came close (close but no cigar):

[Forward Output](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/out_forward) - not supporting ssl connection.

[Secure Forward Output](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/out_secure_forward) - sends data only to another fluentd receiver.

Some were https plugins and some were specific service plugins (which required a token/user/password of some kind).

Is there any other plugin i can use? maybe with some workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending days on searching for an existing plugin, I decided that there is none and I shall write it myself!

[fluent-plugin-loomsystems](https://github.com/loomltd/fluent-plugin-loomsystems)
A fluentd output plugin for secured TCP forwarding :)

To add the plugin to your fluentd agent, use the following command:

```
gem install fluent-plugin-loomsystems
```

To match events and **send them anywhere you'd like**, simply add the following code to your fluentd configuration file.

```
<match **>
  @type loomsystems
  host <your-beloved-host>
</match>
```

After a restart of Fluentd, all flunetd events will be sent to your host.

The plugin opens a new ssl connection by default but can be configured to send on a non secured tcp mode.

```
<match tag-life.**>
  @type loomsystems
  host <your-beloved-host>
  use_ssl false
</match>
```

I welcome you to star, suggest, and contribute the plugin, enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

[@dorony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3142017/dorony) : I was trying to use it but unable to make it work. I am running openshift-3.6.0 locally on docker containers. I added below configuration in fluentd.conf:

```
<match **>
    @type loomsystems
    host 172.17.0.1
    port 4000
    use_ssl false
</match>
```

And below configuration in my logstash input.conf. However i am unable to receive any logs in logstash. Even there is no connection. I am not getting any error in fluentd logs.

```
input {
   tcp {
     codec => fluent
     port => 4000
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :) . Added this match on top and it started working.

Comment: That's great!! Also I personally didn't use the fluent codec in Logstash, because it removed the metadata from my sent messages.

Comment: Yes I also removed this codec as it doesn't work with the current fluentd message structure.